# Options for hiding external siding wires/cables

Tags: siding

We are having our house resided this Spring. We have several sites that run along the exterior. For example our Ethernet cable runs from our study, to the upstairs office (there is no easy way to get it wired up there).
What options are there to hid these unsightly wires?

[image: Ethernet wire running outside]

Comment: The low voltage wires(ethernet,coax, phone) can be placed under the siding(making sure nails do not go into it).

Comment: What do you mean "there is no way"?  There are ways to get low voltage wires through walls and between floors with little to no damage.    Alarm installers are really good at it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network

Comment: Any reason you're running CAT wiring instead of going wireless?

Comment: @LarryBud faster speeds?

Comment: Also, following up on @crip659, you can get siding clips that will slip under the siding and provide a little clamp you can slip the cable to.  So you can run the cable out the hole, along the bottom of the siding piece, to the railing, then use standard cable clamps with nails down the railing.  Hopefully you've got outdoor (UV) rated cable.  (Clip example: https://ezcableclips.com/products/ez-cable-siding-clip-new)

Comment: @Huesmann, sure, but depending on the application it may not matter. Wireless can easily keep up with streaming video these days, for example. Perhaps something he hasn't considered.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is to do a better job of dressing the wire. This could mean running it vertical after a drip loop, or horizontal along or under one of the slats of siding. Since this is a visual item more than a practical one, use your judgement on where you want it to run. So long as you don't remove siding permanently, eliminate the drip loop, or damage the cable, most solutions will work.